# How far can one see off into the distance when up high?

Tags: science-based, physics, map-making

This may seem like a strange question but when I am running pen and paper campaigns and the party enters a new area from somewhere high up (like a mountain overlooking a city) I am always unsure about how to describe what they see because I have no sense of how much distance one can see given the curvature of the world and a given height. Knowing this information would help me design my maps as well as give an appropriate description to the players.

So, leaving out things such as atmospheric conditions and other high objects in the way (assume the vantage point looking out is by far the highest object), **how could I calculate the field of view and distance for an average human**? Other simplifications may be necessary; I'm just looking for a quick and dirty estimate (an equation) that is realistic enough for an RPG where everything is in the player's heads. However, I have seen very complicated answers on this SE so if you want to add more detail please feel free. For the purpose of this answer, assume that we are dealing with Earth.

Comment: This is a question for google or http://physics.stackexchange.com/ 
Unless of course it has to do with the conditions of a different world than our own.

Comment: What Martine said; this is not a question about building a world, so it's off topic for us. It'd be a better fit for [physics.se] or maybe even [math.se] because it's really just trigonometry.

Comment: This is a question for roleplaying, and it has been [answered there already](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6610/a-summary-of-visibility) though it was closed as off-topic there since it did not ask in terms of rpg.

Comment: Fair enough. I just figured that this would factor into building a world - it certainly does for my own worldbuilding and seems more like a worldbuilding question than an RPG one. If the world was for a novel or movie this question could still be relevant for the characters. I asked the question in terms of Earth because it's curvature has a known value. Then anyone could change the formula to the curvature of their world as necessary. I don't know the curvature of my world offhand. Regardless, the roleplaying topic linked above seems to have enough information for me to figure it out.

Comment: Do you want travelling distance or miles?

Comment: Miles. So if I'm designing, say, the exit to a cave high up in a mountain in my fictional world I might say: "From here you are able to see all the way to the walls at the opposite end of the city below" and know that I have calculated this because I know how many miles away the city's edge would be from where the characters are.

Comment: Just because something is relevant *in-universe* does not make it a question about *building* the world. Worldbuilding SE focuses on the imaginary aspects of building a world and how those pieces fit together; if you have a question that is *equally applicable* to *the exact same situation* in the real world, then that question is highly likely off topic here.

Comment: Finding the distance to the visible edge of a circle is a math problem, and even if it wasn't, there is nothing in this question that makes *this question* about anything *imaginary*. (Yes, you say it's for a world in which you set a role-playing game, but we could delete that and the question would remain exactly the same.)

Comment: @ Michael Kjorling I think I see the nuance. Other science-based question on this board consider what would happen if something was altered from how things are in the real world. My question asks about something that is the same in the real world (curvature of my world notwithstanding). For those interested, [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Distance-to-the-Horizon) is one way to do it. Basically, d = R * arccos(R/(R + h)), where d is distance to horizon, R is radius of world, and h is height off the ground. Multiply R by 1.2 to approximate the effects of atmospheric refraction.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty estimate is in imperial units for an Earth size world.

Distance to horizon in miles is half your height in feet.

If you're 6ft tall it's about 3 miles, if you're 100ft up and 6ft tall it's 53 miles.

Comment: That estimate is only good for fairly small heights. If you're 100ft up and 6ft tall, the horizon is about 12 miles away, not 53 miles. A better approximation is that (on the earth) if your eyes are $h$ feet above sea level, the horizon distance in miles is about the square root of 1.5 times $h$.

Comment: @RickDecker you're correct, but the important thing to remember is that it doesn't actually matter